# get pid of process in subprocess python + bash

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to find pid of proccess started in bash script with another program. I use sshpass to enter the password, sshpass start ssh client and that client open sshtunnel to server.
Here is examples:

```
start_tunnel.sh
#!/bin/bash
exec sshpass -p 'passw' ssh -D :port user@$server -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -f -N
exit
```

And I start it with `subrocess.Popen`:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('start_tunnel.sh')
```

The script start just fine, it normally finish and return 0, I can get it PID, but is it possible to get the PID of started sshclient?

Answer (score 1):

By default `proc.pid` will return the PID of the shell (ie the parent process). What you're looking for is the PID of the child process (sshpass).

So set `shell=False` in `subprocess.Popen`. [Documentation is here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid).

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `sshpass` directly from `Popen` and pass in the `shell=False` option. Then the direct child will the be the `sshpass` subprocess. No need for a shell wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for unswers guys, if I do this, I get sshpass PID, but is it possible to get PID of sshclient proccess, which spawned by sshpass proccess?

Answer (score 0):

Using `subprocess.Popen` I would simply call the `shell=false` option.